# Multi-lingual feature in Android app

Tags: android, multilingual

Hello I am trying to make application in different language like French and English.

Suppose there is registration activity where there are two fields like First Name, Last Name then I can display the First Name, Last Name text in English/French. Here in my application there is option to change application language, from there user has changed to French now user started to type email then here I want in French instead of English.

can you please look how I can do such that keyboard should have now French ?

Suppose user has typed details in French here and later user has changed the language of application to English then I need to show the First Name, Last Name in English now which was typed in French. So should I translate French dynamic words to English or any good idea resolve this situation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You question seems unclear. Said in a few words, you want to be able to dynamically change the language of the application's resources. That's it ?

Comment: @Orabîg There is language change feature from my application, if here user has opted "French" then here user keyboard should have now in French

Comment: @Orabîg I don't know what is unclear to you, guys who answered to my question is same which I want to do so and if you read it carefully and completely then it should clear you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the *users* first name and last name to be automatically translated from French to English (does that even make sense?), which is not possible right now, as it requires strong AI.

If you just want the messages "First Name" / "Last Name" to appear either in French or English, have you read the [introduction on languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) and [resources howto](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)?

Keep in mind that your program does not need to change the keyboard - that is the users preference (and I would be quite annoyed if a program would take such initiatives...).

Comment: In my application, user can change the application language and here user has changed to French then it does not make sense if in my android app user can type in EditText in English only still also, here I want keyboard should change to now in French

Comment: Why do you want the user to change the appication language? The usual android style is that the app language is the same as the system display (not keyboard!) language.

Comment: Yes, Hmm I agree but that is my requirement that client introduced to do so

Comment: and second question -- Suppose user has typed details in French here and later user has changed the language of application to English then I need to show the First Name, Last Name Value like "Tassos Bassoukos" in English now which was typed in French. How can I translate French dynamic words to English or any other good approach to resolve this situation ?

Comment: In my experience, [this cartoon](http://tamingdata.com/2010/07/08/the-project-management-tree-swing-cartoon-past-and-present/) applies - tell your client that the language will be autodetected, and the user will not need to choose. Otherwise you will need to dig deep into the framework to fiddle with the bits that your app needs.

Comment: You cannot translate dynamic words that the user has entered - present them in original French and perhaps give the user the option of editing/amending them in the new language - I'm Greek and if you tried automatic translation to greek names the results would range from hilarious to offensive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to tell the user's keyboard what language to use, unless you implement your own keyboard. Since you are entering names and emails, you can probably get by with a simple keyboard without word suggestions or corrections, which would allow you to use a simple [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) and prevent the usual keyboard from appearing using your Activity's [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

For the translation, I think your best option would be to try to use an online translator API. Still, I think I agree with the other replies in saying that you should try to work out a more realistic design with your clients.